# Как в цикле разделить для каждой видеокарты память?

Tags: c#

```
private static int int1024 = 1048576;

ManagementObjectSearcher Vd 
= new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");

    ManagementObjectCollection Video = Vd.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject w in Video)
                {
                    string gpuTotalMem = String.Format("{0} ", (Convert.ToDouble(w["AdapterRam"]) / int1024).ToString());
                    if (w["Caption"] != null)
                    StringBild.AppendFormat("Ваша Видеокарта: {0} :  {1} [Bytes]", w["Caption"], gpuTotalMem);
                }
```

[image: Вывод памяти с видеокарты]

Для 2-ой показывает (`2176 МБ`) - тут нормально!

А для 1-ой показывает (`2048 MB`) - А тут должно быть `2 ГБ`

**Как показывает у меня:**

> Ваша Видеокарта: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M - (2048 MB)
>
> Ваша Видеокарта: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 - (2176 MB)

Comment: но ведь  `2048 MB` - это правильный результат.. округлите то 1 цифры если память 20** MB.. или в чем тут сложность?

Comment: Я хотел сделать чтобы показывало точное значение как на картинке.

Comment: Так в чем проблема-то? Вам нужно написать просто дополнительный код, который проверяет, если число мегабайт можно привести к целому числу гигабайт, то привести, иначе вывести в мегабайтах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверяем, есть ли остаток от деления 1024. Если остатка нет, то делим ещё на 1024 и приписываем " ГБ". Ели есть остаток от деления, то приписываем " МБ".

```
 foreach (ManagementObject w in Video)
            {
                string gpuTotalMem;
                if((Convert.ToDouble(w["AdapterRam"]) / int1024) % 1024 == 0){
                    gpuTotalMem = ((Convert.ToDouble(w["AdapterRam"]) / int1024) / 1024).ToString() + " ГБ";
                } else {
                    gpuTotalMem = (Convert.ToDouble(w["AdapterRam"]) / int1024).ToString() + " МБ";
                }
                if (w["Caption"] != null)
                StringBild.AppendFormat("Ваша Видеокарта: {0} :  {1} ", w["Caption"], gpuTotalMem);
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)